# Inserting utf-8 encoded string to list in python

Tags: python-2.7, list, file-io, utf-8

I am trying to read the contents of the file into a list. However, the file contents may contain some non-ASCII characters. I have used "utf-8" encoding while reading and also encoding each line read while inserting to the list. When I try to print the list it still shows characters in non-ASCII format. I want it to be in a plain string so that I can perform some string operations like find.
Any help will be appreciated.

- file=[temp.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/813mlmseuob6lzo/temp.txt?dl=0)
- contents=
  European Commission. (2005). Business Case for Diversity - Good Practices in the Workplace. Luxemburg: Ofice for Oficial Publications of the European Communities
  Hardmeier, Sibylle & Vinz, Dagmar. (2007). Diversity und Intersectionality. Eine kritische Würdigung der Ansätze für die Politikwissenschaft. Femina Politica. Zeitschrift für feministische Politikwissenschaft, 16 (1), 23-33
  Kahlert, Heike. (2003). Gender Mainstreaming an Hochschulen - Anleitung zum qualitätsbewussten Handeln. Opladen: Leske + Budrich

code written-

```
import os
import io
f = io.open(os.path.join(path,"temp.txt"),mode="r",encoding="utf8")
lines = [line.encode('utf-8').rstrip('\n') for line in f]
print lines
```

Comment: It's unclear where the newlines are so it's hard to determine what your expected output is

Comment: I apologize for the bad formatting. I have updated the question with the link to the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

When you open and read the file with `encoding="utf8"`, it already does the decoding for you. Your `line.encode('utf-8')` that follows only serves to make it a `bytearray` and no longer plain text. Remove `.encode('utf-8')` and it should be fine.

Comment: I have tried that but the output is still incorrect-
[u'European Commission. (2005). Business Case for Diversity - Good Practices in the Workplace. Luxemburg: Ofice for Oficial Publications of the European Communities', u'Hardmeier, Sibylle & Vinz, Dagmar. (2007). Diversity und Intersectionality. Eine kritische W\xfcrdigung der Ans\xe4tze f\xfcr die Politikwissenschaft. Femina Politica. Zeitschrift f\xfcr feministische Politikwissenschaft, 16 (1), 23-33', u'Kahlert, Heike. (2003). Gender Mainstreaming an Hochschulen - Anleitung zum qualit\xe4tsbewussten Handeln. Opladen: Leske + Budrich']

Comment: Try changing `.encode('utf-8')` to `.decode('utf-8')` then.

Comment: Got this exception -> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc'

Comment: Try using `codecs.open` instead of `io.open`, and remove `.encode('utf-8')` again then.

Comment: Still no success. the code works but when I print the list the string elements are not formatted

Comment: This answer is fine, but you should ignore the further suggestions in comments. The output you see with `W\xfcrdigung` is correct. When you call `print` on a list, it will use `repr` formatting for its elements, which shows differently than when calling `print` on a Unicode string directly; cf. `print u'Würdigung'` vs. `print repr(u'Würdigung')` – the second has quote characters and escape sequences, the first doesn't. If you want to see `ü` instead of `\xfc`, print each string separately, or switch to Python 3.